# What settings do I use for Carbon Copy Cloner if I want everything exactly the same on my new SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, osx-snow-leopard, ssd, upgrade, disk-cloning

I am upgrading from a hard drive to an SSD and looking at Carbon Copy Cloner 3.4.5. However I am uncertain what settings I should use as far as handling data already on the destination. Essentially I am expecting the destination to be completely empty after I just partitioned it, but I am a little bit confused about all the options available.

What I want is essentially everything the same on my mac running snow leopard as it was before except residing on an SSD, so what settings should I use? There are customizable settings and advanced settings.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you probably just want one single partition as Mac OS Extended, Journaled, on the SSD. If you've partitioned the destination, it's completely empty, so that's okay. CCC will try to archive existing files, but if there's nothing, what's there to archive?

CCC is designed to make this as intuitive as possible. From the Carbon Copy Cloner documentation:

> #### [I want to clone my entire hard drive to a new hard drive or a new machine](http://help.bombich.com/kb/usage-scenarios/i-want-to-clone-my-entire-hard-drive-to-a-new-hard-drive-or-a-new-machine)
>
> In this situation, it would be ideal to simply copy off the entire contents of your hard drive to an external hard drive — to create a "bootable clone" of your production machine. You can then boot a loaner machine from this bootable clone and work from it as if working from your original machine.
>
> - Launch Carbon Copy Cloner
> - Choose the volume that you want to clone from the Source menu
> - Choose a properly-formatted volume from the Destination menu
> - Select "Temporarily archive modified and deleted items" from the preconfigured settings menu
> - Click the Clone button

And, to be honest, nothing stops you from just trying it. There's nothing to lose if you only clone your existing HDD to the SSD.